# React default create-react-app App component rendered twice

Tags: reactjs

I started new React project via the command:

`npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

Then, I changed the App component to look like that:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component<{}> {
  public render() {
    console.log("App Rendered");
    return (
      <div>
        Hello World
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and when I watch the Console log ( both in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge ) I receive this messages:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
App Rendered
App Rendered
```

My Questions:
Why the App render is being called **twice**?
How to remove the first message with that WDS?

This is my `package.json` ( default one as I ran `create-react-app` ):

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: WDS - Webpack dev server

Comment: @jonrsharpe how can I disable that message?

Comment: Why do you want to disable *any* of the messages? What's the *problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: It is not normal that the App component is being rendered twice, why it's happen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When wrapped with `React.StrictMode` (which is how [CRA template](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template-typescript/template/src/index.tsx) are setup), on development, renders will be called twice. This is done to catch bugs that might occurs when some setState functions are not pure. You can read [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-390206425) for more detail.

Comment: To be fair I submitted @Kirill 's answer since he answered first, but thanks for the information, I am sure it will be useful to others as well.

Comment: @Dorki since this answer actually answers the question, it would make more sense to make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `React.StrictMode` from src/index.tsx